# What is the difference for linux kernel :module or built-in?

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel

In linux, many drivers (and some parts) can be compiled directly in the kernel or as a module. Is there any difference between compiling a driver (or some parts) as a module and compiling it directly? They seem to work either ways. Also, Are there some pros and cons in compiling it as a module or compiling it directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is compiled in the linux kernel it will be part of the binary forever. So, it wont be loaded into the kernel on a "as-needed" basis. So, for example assume you have a realtek ethernet card on your machine why do you need drivers for intel ethernet cards?

One other thing, kernel modules in general can not reference a function in the kernel unless it is exported to modules using `EXPORT_SYMBOL` and its variants. So, if your driver need to reference functions from the kernel sources (which should not be the case anyways) then you have to add your driver into the kernel source tree.